# Recurrent workflow stops after a number of iterations

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

A workflow is started upon instantiation of the the entity *Hazaa*. It waits for a while and then creates a new instance of *Hazaa*. After that, it's put to sleep as *successful*.

I'd expect it to fire perpetually creating a bunch of *Hazaas*. However, I only get 15 new ones before the procreations cease. Together with the original one that I create manually to set off the workflow-flow, there's 16 instances in total. I've tested with longer delays (up to several hours) but the behavior is consistent.

That's for CRM On-line. On premise, the behavior is similar but limited to 8 instances in grand total.

According to the harvest of links I've found, there's a setting in CRM to control the number of iterations. The problem is that my solution will be mainly deployed for on-line customers so unless I own the cloud, that's a show stopper.

I understand it's CRM protecting against the recurrence. What can I do about it?

The best solution I can think of at the moment is to set up a super workflow, firing the sub workflow 16 times. Then I'd need to have a super super workflow etc. Not a braggable in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CorrelationToken` contains a counter and a one-hour "self-destruct" timer.

When the first workflow runs, a new `CorrelationToken` is created. The counter is set to 1 and the timer is set to one hour.

When the second workflow is started from the first workflow (even indirectly, such as in your case), this same `CorrelationToken` is used *if its self-destruct timer has not already expired*. If it has, a new `CorrelationToken` is created. If it hasn't, it increments the counter and resets the timer. Lather, rinse, repeat.

The second (and subsequent) workflows will only execute if the counter is 8 or less (On-Premise) or 16 or less (CRM Online)

What this really means is that in practice, if your child workflows are executing sooner than one hour apart, the `CorrelationToken` never gets a chance to expire, which means eventually the counter increments past the limit. It **does not** mean that you can execute up to 8 (or 16) of these workflows every hour.

It sounds like you already figured most of this out, but I wanted to give other readers background. So, to answer your question: if your design includes looping workflows that are executed sooner than one hour apart, you will need to consider an alternate design. It will definitely involve an external process or service.

Comment: First of all - thanks for a very elaborative and informative answer. I'll make sure to test it right away. **However**, I'm not sure it's going to help because I've tried the time span of 90 minutes as well and still got only a limited number of *Hazaas*. I'll give it one more whack and see what happens. Also, would you care to throw in a link to where you got this splendid information? Or is it the kind of knowledge that one has obtained by tearing ones hair out during trial-and-horror?

Comment: Here is a good post to read through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600161/why-is-infinite-loop-protection-being-triggered-on-my-crm-workflow

Comment: I'm not sure the CorrelationToken stuff is documented anywhere, that is just good ol' observation (and hair pulling). It kind of makes sense when you think about it though - it allows CRM to detect infinite loops in a stateless way.

Comment: It makes sense to block the iterations. It doesn't make sense to do it in this way and with so poor documentation. Maybe MS has a deal with Regaine... Anyhow, I have a test ticking right now. In just a short off 16*75 minutes we'll know. It'll be 20 thrilling hours with excitement level comparable to watching snails copulate. :)

Comment: By the way, is the 60 minutes limit per installation, per firing entity type or per workflow instance? I'm thinking that it should be possible to start four or five different *Hazaas* and let each of them procreate after more then an hour. The combined effect would be that the executions are only a quarter of an hour apart, right?

Comment: It is per CorrelationToken, if that makes sense. I've never tested it to this level, but I assume that you could define 9 different workflows on 9 different entities. If you set it up in such a way that each workflow triggered the next, with each step taking no longer than an hour, CRM would still think it was an infinite loop and kill it because the CorrelationToken is the same. I agree with your assumption - each should have its own CorrelationToken in that case.

Comment: Allright! When I set the delay to 75 minutes, the *Hazaas* keep appearing. Now, I only need to figure out how to trick CRM into doing that in parallel, simultaneous workflows. I have a plugin that is invoked when a *Hazaa* us created. I'd prefer not to register the same plugin for creation message of entity types *Hazaa1*, *Hazaa2* etc. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your base requirement, but either way it is probably best to create a new question for it since SO is begging us to move this thread to chat already. Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like you're creating an infinite loop, which is why the CRM kills workflows like these, since otherwise they'll never end. On what condition would you stop making more Hazaa records? You could add a number field and increment that field on each new Hazaa and when it reaches a certain number stop the workflow.

Comment: For the same of the issue, let's say I'd like to run the workflow 17 times. I.e. the one that I manually trigger and 16 (as opposed to 15) extra before the CRM cuts me off. Also, please keep in mind that the workflow of mine doesn't trigger itself directly - it rather creates an instance of *Hazaa* (which is connected to triggering a new workflow call) and, at the end of its execution, it kills itself. No danger for overheating the system by recurrence, unless run too often.